# Computed Column cannot be Persisted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a custom function, and I am trying to created a persisted column using this function.

It is giving me following error.

> Computed column 'FormattedSSN' in table 'SomeTable' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Here is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatSSN]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
AS
BEGIN
    return '';
END
```

Here is the query to add the column using the function:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable
ADD FormattedSSN as dbo.FormatSSN() PERSISTED
```

Please suggest if there is any way out. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add **WITH SCHEMABINDING** to the function like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatSSN]
(
@SSN    VARCHAR(9)
)
RETURNS CHAR(11)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  your stuff here
END
```

and then run this to verify:

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FormatSSN]'),'IsDeterministic') = 1
   PRINT 'Function is detrministic.'
ELSE IF OBJECTPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FormatSSN]'),'IsDeterministic') = 0
   PRINT 'Function is NOT detrministic'
GO
```

Works here.

Comment: Awesome. But how is this function different(behavior) from regular function?

Comment: Thanks. I knew about SCHEMABINDING in other contexts (e.g. views). It seems it will work pretty much same here. Any change to table will throw an error.

Answer (score 5):

How about specifying the definition directly:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable
ADD FormattedSSN as
    case when len(EmployeeSSN) = 9 then
            substring(EmployeeSSN, 1, 3) + '-' +
            substring(EmployeeSSN, 4, 2) + '-' +
            substring(EmployeeSSN, 6, 4)
    else EmployeeSSN end
PERSISTED
```

Comment: Yay!...it worked :)...
Can you explain why? Whats the difference between this and the one I posted? Whether it gonna work same way?

Comment: The engine cannot tell what side effects the UDF might have, as it could be modified later, and the cached plan for it is recomputed each time it is run.  When representing the computed column as a SQL expression, it knows there are no non-deterministic side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling the UDF, Set the computed column expression to

```
Case When Len(EmployeeSSN) = 0 Then 
      SUBSTRING(EmployeeSSN, 1, 3) + '-' + 
      SUBSTRING(EmployeeSSN, 4, 2) + '-' + 
      SUBSTRING(EmployeeSSN, 6, 4)
    Else EmployeeSSN End
```

In the Create Table script you can add a column:

```
[NewColumnName]  As
   (Case When len([UpdateUserId])=(0) T
         Then (((substring([UpdateUserId],(1),(3))+'-')+
                 substring([UpdateUserId],(4),(2)))+'-')+
                 substring([UpdateUserId],(6),(4)) 
         Else [UpdateUserId] End) PERSISTED,
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a non-computed column of appropriate datatype. Create an Insert trigger (and an Update trigger if data will change). You can then persist the function output in a column.

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD FormattedSSN VARCHAR(11)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_I_SomeTable ON  dbo.SomeTable AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update s
    set s.FormattedSSN = dbo.FormatSSN()
    from SomeTable AS s
        join inserted i on i.id = s.id

END
GO
```

Comment: This great for non-deterministic functions, like `FORMAT`. Thanks!